# How to check users remove to service worker

Tags: web-push

I am trying to find a solution for FCM. I can't know endpoint exists if user removes it. Help me. I have researched google document for FCM but no solution. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to POST a notification to that endpoint you must verify the HTTP status code returned.

For example if you get `410 Gone`, then you must remove that endpoint because it is expired.

See also this post: http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2016/05/the-push-api-and-its-wild-unsubscription-mechanism/